# Cannot print after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, release-management

After I upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04, I am able to scan from my Canon MP190 printer but it does not print.

An internet search shows that this is a common fault. Can a software update be expected? Thank you in anticipation.